# How to restore the row with cell values in inlinenav jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

It is possible to restore the row of inlinenav jqgrid with my own cell values(hard coded values) as we do restore row with rowId like,
$(#grid).jqgrid("restoreRow", rowId);

I have a row with three columns, i want to restore my row with my own cell data. Is there any way to do so?

Please help me achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqGrid saves the current editable value in `savedRow` parameter. During working of `restoreRow` jqGrid uses the values: it calls `setRowData` with the saved value.

You wrote that you use `inlineNav`. It means that you don't call the method `restoreRow` **directly**. Instead on that jqGrid calls `restoreRow` if the user select another row or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. To be able to modify the standard behavior of `restoreRow` you have to use callbacks/events, which jqGrid calls/triggers during processing of `restoreRow`. Thus it's important to know *which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid* because the set of callbacks/events and the exact behavior depend on the fork and the version used. I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork and recommend you to use it.

The method `restoreRow` supports `beforeCancelRow` and `afterrestorefunc` callbacks, which you can use to solve your problem. You can change some properties of `savedRow` inside of `beforeCancelRow` to solve your problem. Alternatively you can just make one more call of `setRowData` inside of `afterrestorefunc` to set the column value of restored row to the value, which you want to have. The exact specifying of `beforeCancelRow` or `afterrestorefunc` callbacks in `inlineNav` depends on the version/fork of jqGrid. You should post the information if you would have implementation problem based on my above description.

Comment: Awesome comments. Thanks a lot. My code as per ur sugesstion: $("#Mygrid"),jqgrid("restoreRow", lastsel, {"afterrestorefunc":function(response){$("#Mygrid"),jqgrid('setRowData', lastsel, {Name: "XXX", Age:"YYY", Gender:"ZZZ"}}}); Working fine.